# question about gpl commitment

Tags: license

On https://choosealicense.com/licenses/gpl-2.0/ 3 in the optional steps section it talks about

> "If you would like your project to adopt the GPL-3.0’s cure provision, add the text of the GPL Cooperation Commitment to a file named COMMITMENT in the same directory as your GPL-2.0 license file."

I was wondering what would change if I added/had the Commitment compared to not adding/having it? In laymen terms. I understand it as adding in a period that a issue can be resolved, but not sure if I am correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GPL Cooperation Commitment is a promise from you that you will not (continue to) litigate for copyright violation if the person violating the GPL license shows good faith and takes the proper steps to comply with the license.

This promise is an integral part of GPLv3, but it is not part of the GPLv2. Some companies have decided to give that promise anyway. It might make your software slightly more attractive, especially if you are a big corporation and your software is used by individual developers, because the developers using your software in their products have less to fear if they accidentally infringe upon the license.

Comment: Thanks for answering and giving details about the commitment. I have decided it would be beneficial to everyone that uses my code to have/use this commitment.